# Linux command to count number of occurrences of a string in a specific file type within the whole dir

Tags: linux

i used the following cmd to count lines of class appears within h extension files

```
grep -rc 'class' --include \*.h mydirc|wc -l
```

however, i think the result is wrong when i add up the number of occurrence for each file, it's wrong. I found the wc -l was actually counting the number of files that was searched and printed on the screen. For exmaple,

```
/afs/eos/dist/ds5-2013.06/FastModelsTools_8.2/OSCI/Syst...sc_buffer.h:6
```

i added the number of h: up, it didn't match the final value. The final value actually matches the number of printed lines on the sreen which is the same as the number of .h extension files it has searched.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer you acknowledged as working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
find . -name \*.h | xargs grep class | wc -l
```

Comment: so the thing is the -c flag i used in grep.People were saying we should use it, which was totally a mistake.